# Visualizing a region on x-y plane in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

How can I make a plot in R of the region, where it must fulfill
$$
\mathbb{E}\big[\log(x Z^2_t+y)\big]<0,
$$
where $Z_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Thanks!

Comment: I removed the time series and GARCH tags since they are pretty tangential to the question. The crux seems to be how to use R to visualize a certain equation on a plane.

Comment: @RichardHardy The GARCH tags are *not* incidental. The value of that expectation is equation 54 in [Nelson (1990)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3532198), without which it is not possible to plot the required chart (without simulation).

Comment: @tchakravarty, I get the point, but I think that is tangential. It is OK to mention GARCH in the text but a tag is not necessary, IMHO. In general, the plot could be based on the price of apples, some feature of a DNA sequence, a GARCH model or whatever not. Importantly, the solution of the problem will not depend in any way on where the equation came from. But opinions may differ.

Comment: @RichardHardy so you would suggest re-proving Nelson's theorem 6 to answer this question? Best of luck to you. :-)

Comment: @tchakravarty, probably I misunderstood. The question is phrased, how do I plot something *in R*. If the question was, how does this equation look like in general, what contour plots it produces or the like, it would be a different thing. Then also it would fit Maths Stackexchange better than Cross Validated.

Comment: @RichardHardy You are missing a crucial part of the question, I feel. You need statistical insight (provided by Nelson's theorem 6) to know how to plot the expectation (again, without resorting to simulation). By that token, this question is a perfect fit for CV. I urge you to look at the linked paper to see what I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43804/discussion-between-richard-hardy-and-tchakravarty).

Comment: @tchakravarty The connection with statistics is welcome.  Among other things, your reference suggests $0 \lt y \lt 1$. This is critical, because the expression for the expectation as a combination of generalized hypergeometric functions involves enormous cancellations of large values when $y\gg 1$, rendering it impossible for `R` to calculate.  However, statistical insight isn't necessary to obtain Nelson's Theorem 6.  For instance, *Mathematica* readily produces a (slightly simpler) value.  That brings the question down to one of numerical analysis.

Comment: @whuber Lots of statistical derivations are routine & mechanical. That is perfectly compatible with them being statistical. The presence of the expectation operator makes this a statistical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sampling and ggplot2:

```
expected <- function(x, y, samples = 1000) {
  mean(log(x * rnorm(samples)^2 + y), na.rm = TRUE)
}
inputs <- seq(-5, 5, .1)
grid <- expand.grid(inputs, inputs)
grid$output <- unlist(Map(expected, grid$Var1, grid$Var2))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(grid, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = output < 0)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

Comment: To get precision comparable to the plot shown in the paper referenced by @tchakravarty, this code would have to run for years.